# Prevent full screen menu from scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I have a full-screen menu and once active the page still scrolls, is there a way to stop this?

I read another post that stated to

```
    body,html {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

but this stops the page from scrolling as well.

Comment: can you share some more code?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Could you please be more specific, and do share some more code if possible as @mrblue mentioned.

Comment: Show what is in your index.html file

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider some JS/Jquery to enable / disable a fixed class when the menu toggles open and closed?

for example

```js
if($('#menu').hasClass('open'))
 {
    $('body').addClass("fixedPosition");
 }
 else
 {
    $('body').removeClass("fixedPosition");
 }
```